# How to remove a record from the entity - MVVM, WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have the following code in ViewModel, I would like to remove a record from an entity but it doesn't work. Can someone please shed some light...?

```
Usertable users = new Usertable();
users.User_ID = Entity.User_ID;
users.user_role = "Admin";
Entity.CompanyRoles.Remove(users);
```

Instead if I replace the Remove with Add, it will add one record to the entity.

Only Remove is a concern to me.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to fetch the entity you are about to remove, then remove it, then save your changes to the datacontext:

```
var userToRemove = Entity.CompanyRoles.Single(cr => cr.user_role == "Admin");
Entity.CompanyRoles.DeleteObject(userToRemove);
Entity.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Don't forget that in depending on the EF version he'll have to change the ObjectState as well.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are compared by reference, not values, so unless `Entity.CompanyRoles` contains the exact reference in memory as the object you're trying to remove, it won't find the object in the collection and remove it.

There are two ways to fix it.

The best way is to get a reference to the object in the collection like [Paul suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12676952/302677)

```
var userToRemove = Entity.CompanyRoles.Single(cr => 
    cr.user_role == "Admin" && cr.User_ID = Entity.User_ID);

Entity.CompanyRoles.Remove(userToRemove);
```

Or another method that works is to overwrite the `.Equals()` of the object to consider them equal if the data is the same, regardless of the memory reference. I would not usually recommend this except in special cases since it affects any operation that compares one copy of this object to another using `.Equals()`

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null || !(obj == MyClass))
        return false; 

    var obj2 = obj as MyClass;

    return obj2.user_role == this.user_role && obj2.User_ID == this.User_ID;
}
```

Comment: thanks Rachel...ur first way worked...but ended up with one error....I have this code in a foreach loop on the entity....every time I remove a record from it...it hits the below error...collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute. entity framework

Comment: @siddu You can't modify a collection while you're looping through it, so usually I loop through the items to be removed and remove each one from the collection, instead of looping through the collection and looking for items to remove. Often this requires creating a temporary collection to hold the items to remove.